# Declaring functions in es6 modules in an angular app

Tags: angular, import, es6-modules, angular-module

My angular MonoRepo contains many app and a lot of publishable libraries.

Many of my apps and libs are sharing some utils functions: *groupBy*, *parsers*...

I've created a lib called `utils` and declare there those functions.

**aLib**

```js
import { groupBy } from '@mono/utils';
// other imports
    
@Component({
  selector: 'app-homepage',
  templateUrl: './homepage.html',
  styleUrls: ['./homepage.scss']
})
export class Homepage implements OnInit {
    //  I call the groupBy function into the component of my lib
myData = groupBy(a, 'key');
```

When I learnt angular I saw nowhere that way to do. All the tutorials I learnt explains that every function should be wrap by an angular module.
=> create an angular module that contains a service where each of those function would be declare.

I think that that option is overEngineering and  instead of importing one unique function I will have to import the whole module

Is there any probleme doing it that way?

Comment: You don’t need a module and you can import any es6 export where ever you need it..

Comment: I know I can, that's what I do. But question is: is it the angular way to do it? All Angular tutorials describe how to use services and DI. What about simple import of es6 ?

Comment: In the end, it’s just javascript so it is perfectly fine to have stand-alone utility functions done like that..